# SQLite Compare Orders

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have a table with two columns `a1` and `a2`.

I need to check if the sequence order of this table is the same, when I order it by `a1` and if I order it by `a2`.

`Select a1, a2 from Test order by a1`

| a1 | a2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

`Select a1, a2 from Test order by a2`

| a1 | a2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

Is it somehow possible to check if both results are actually the same, respecting the order of each output?

I tried something like:

```sql
With order_1 as (Select * from Test order by a1),
     order_2 as (Select * from Test order by a2)

Select * from order_1 except Select * from order_2
```

This should yield something like:

| a1 | a2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

But this doesn't work, as it apparently doesn't respect the order.

Comment: your CTEs are named `order_1` and `order_2`, but in your select statement, you refer to `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: SQL uses a set based algebra, specifically SQL tables are modelled after unordered sets of records.  That is, there is no internal order to a SQL table.  If you can more clearly explain what you are trying to achieve, maybe more can be said.

Comment: Is there a reason that you accepted an answer that does not return your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY` in a CTE to find the entries which are not in the same position when we use the 2 different keys to sort.
Here we have inversed 3 and 4.

> ```
> create table sorter (
> a1 int, a2 int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into sorter values
> (1,100),(2,200),(3,400),(4,300),(5,500);
> ```

> ```
> with cte as (
> select 
>   a1,
>   a2,
>   row_number() over (order by a1) rna1,
>   row_number() over (order by a2) rna2
> from sorter)
> select
>   a1,
>   a2
> from cte where rna1 <> rna2;
> ```
>
> ```
> a1 |  a2
> -: | --:
>  3 | 400
>  4 | 300
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4a9b291febaa680e36c1c337afee111c)*

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function twice for each of the columns `a1` and `a2` in a cte and then a self join of the cte to filter out the matching rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a1) rn_a1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a2) rn_a2
  FROM Test 
)
SELECT c1.a1, c1.a2
FROM cte c1 INNER JOIN cte c2
ON c1.rn_a1 = c2.rn_a2 AND (c1.a1, c1.a2) <> (c2.a1, c2.a2) 
ORDER BY c1.a1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e80ad4463c7450451d989d097add0255).

Results:

| a1 | a2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |